# why my IDE can't Auto-Complete for python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

when i use python-docx , my IDE ,like pycharm wing , can't Auto-Complete it.
this code

```
from docx import Document

asd = Document()
asd.add_heading("test")
asd.save("cao.docx")
```

when i typing asd. add_heading can't Auto-Complete.

```
from docx.document import Document  

asd = Document()
asd.save()
this code can Auto-Complete
but atention
```

TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'element' and 'part'

***I am sorry for my poor english***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latter case, you are mistakenly importing `docx.document.Document` rather than `docx.Document`. The `Document` class in `docx.document` has a different call signature and in any case isn't the one you want :)

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, `docx.Document(...)` is actually a function, which returns an object of the `docx.document.Document` class.
*(Perhaps they should have named this method by following the naming convention, say something like docx.create_document(...))*

Hence, you shall use both the following imports, in order to get the visibility of the contents of `docx.document.Document` class:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.document import Document
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it shows how to solve the issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me only the following worked for PyCharm 2023.1:

```py
from docx import Document as CreateDocument
from docx.document import Document

document: Document = CreateDocument()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this workaround to have the autocomplete feature in your IDE and not get the `TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'element' and 'part'` :

```
from docx.document import Document
try:
    document = Document()
except TypeError:
    from docx import Document
    document = Document()
```